# tSQLt failure when attempting to SpyProcedure a synonym SP

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, stored-procedures, tsqlt

I am new to tSQLt. I am writing a test for a stored procedure that calls an sp on a different DB. This external SP is set as a synonym in the DB I use. To enhance, this is what I have:

- **SP1 on DB1**
- **SP2 on DB2**
- **SP1 calls SP2**
- **DB2.dbo.SP2 defined as a SYN (Synonyms) on DB1**

***I want to test SP1 without dependency on SP2 results.*** Therefore I want to use tSQLt.SpyProcedure on SP2, but what I tried so far erred:

- **`SpyProcedure @ProcedureName = '[DB2].[dbo].[SP2]'`** : "(Error) Cannot use SpyProcedure on [DB2].[dbo].[SP2] because the procedure does not exist[16,10]{tSQLt.Private_ValidateProcedureCanBeUsedWithSpyProcedure,8}"
- **`SpyProcedure @ProcedureName = '[SYN]'`** : "(Error) Cannot use SpyProcedure on [SYN] because the procedure does not exist[16,10]{tSQLt.Private_ValidateProcedureCanBeUsedWithSpyProcedure,8}"

*** I also tried one less straight-forward solution, but it failed as well:

- **`FakeTable @TableName = sys.procedures`** the logic behind was to fake the system table, than add the full SP path to it (DB2.dbo.SP2) but this erred - "(Error) FakeTable could not resolve the object name, '[sys.procedures]'. (When calling tSQLt.FakeTable, avoid the use of the @SchemaName parameter, as it is deprecated.)[16,10]{tSQLt.Private_ValidateFakeTableParameters,12}"

Any ideas? I tried debugging the "private" methods, but so far couldn't figure out a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on the SpyProcedure documentation, tSQLt can't spy on procedures in other databases. You'll need to rearrange your code a little so that db1.dbo.sp1 calls db1.dbo.sp3, which is just a wrapper around db2.dbo.sp2, then you can use SpyProcedure on db1.dbo.sp3 in your tests.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'll check to see if this fits my needs. Thanks!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I did some googling but still not sure what do you mean by "db1.dbo.sp1 calls db1.dbo.sp3, which is just a wrapper around db2.dbo.sp2". If you can share some info/links on this, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is what it sounds like. db1.dbo.sp3 has no code of its own, it just execs db2.dbo.sp2 passing in the parameters it was given.

Comment: @Noga there are a plans to implement SpyProcedure synonyms functionality in the next few months, so track github project for the latest updates

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks!!! That's a nice work around. Not sure that the dba's manager will like it as it means uploading this sp to prod, but maybe we have a way to exclude it. Anyway, nice and simple so thanks again

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev good to know! Thanks